# How I can use a text file in LWP?

Tags: perl

I need to send requests to an HTTP server using `LWP`. For example, I have a file with data, and I must send requests to server `foobar.baz`.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("$0/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/8.0") 

$req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.foobar.baz');
$req->header('Accept' => 'text/html');
$res = $ua->request($req);
```

How I can use `file.txt` in

```
$req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.foobar.baz')
```

for every request?

For example `file.txt` contains

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
```

I need to send a request to

```
aaaa.foobar.baz
bbbb.foobar.baz
cccc.foobar.baz
```

and so on.

How can I do it?

Comment: Your "txt-file" appears in your question as a bulleted list. If you're talking about a plain text file (ASCII?), format it as code. Are the lines of the text file just numbers, or do they have a leading `- `?

Comment: @KeithThompson, no no, its just for example. txt contain only strings, I need every string add to $$.foobar.baz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple question, and I wonder why you can't even attempt it yourself

It's just a matter of reading the file and building the complete URL from each line of text

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("$0/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/8.0");

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    next unless /\S/;

    chomp;

    my $res = $ua->get( "$_.foobar.baz" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find [`App::SimpleScan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::SimpleScan) on CPAN to be useful. I wrote it for just such an application back at Yahoo! in 2005. It handles combinatorial specifications of URLs, lets you snapshot the output, etc. Plugin-based with a fairly good set of plugins, so if it won't do exactly what you want out of the box, it shouldn't be hard for you to make it work.

Comment: Your answer would be much more useful if it contained code that shows how to solve OP's requirements.

Comment: The code I recommended is a full application, rather than just a module. I'll update to build out an example.